# Joining 3 tables from a database gives me an ambiguous column name error

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to join 3 tables. Right now I'm just trying to run code in sqlite3 CLI but my ultimate goal is to run my query in python with `.execute`.

The .schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER, 
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    hash TEXT NOT NULL,
    cash NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 10000.00,
    PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username ON users (username);

CREATE TABLE stocks (
    id INTEGER,
    symbol TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    stockID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    userID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (stockID) REFERENCES stocks(id)
);
```

My query is in python and looks like this:

```
SELECT users.username, transactions.id, stocks.symbol 
FROM users
INNER JOIN users ON users.id=transactions.userID
INNER JOIN transactions ON transactions.stockID=stocks.id;
```

This gives me a `Error: in prepare, ambiguous column name: users.username (1)`

I have tried `SELECT users.username FROM users;` and that gives me all the usernames.

When I try to join two tables I get the same type of error.

I used [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to learn joining tables but I don't understand where I am going wrong here.

Comment: You are joining users twice instead of a join to stocks.

Comment: I don't understand. What should I be doing?

Comment: You should join users to transactions and then join to stocks.

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing with `INNER JOIN users ON users.id=transactions.userID`?

Comment: `FROM users INNER JOIN users....` joins users to users.

Comment: Ahh ok. So I need to do something like this: `FROM users INNER JOIN transactions ... INNER JOIN stocks ...`
Which will visually look something like this: `users >--< transactions >--< stocks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written your join query in the wrong way. I think you just need to swap the table's name. It would be like this

```sql
SELECT users.username, transactions.id, stocks.symbol 
FROM users
INNER JOIN transactions ON users.id=transactions.userID
INNER JOIN stocks ON transactions.stockID=stocks.id;
```

Try to run this query. I hope it will run correctly.

Comment: Ok this works but why?

Comment: Welcome, @alamin. Please be sure to pay attention to your formatting. I've edited your post to improve the formatting. Please review so you know how to format your posts in the future.